# Пространства имен

Tags: php, namespace

Изучаю сейчас пространства имен, и я запутался немного...

Вот в фреймворке YII2, в контроллерах есть такой код:

```
1. namespace app\controllers;
2. use Yii;
3. use yii\web\Controller;
```

Есть вот два таких вопроса...

1. Мы пишем "use Yii;", и вот на этот момент уже должен быть подключен файл с этим классом, или механизм пространства имен сам подключит его, когда увидит "use"?...
2. "use Yii;" - вот здесь, мы получается "импортируем" класс Yii? Я правильно понимаю? И этот класс лежит сейчас в области видимости app\controllers? Ведь там не из глобальной области видимости пытается подключить.

Answer (score 3):

1. Нет. Конструкция `use SomeNamespace\SomeClass` всего лишь дает нам возможность использовать этот `SomeClass` не указавая каждый раз его пространство имен

Например у нас есть класс:

```
namespace aSpace;
class A{
    ....
}
```

Тогда в другом неймспейсе нам придется либо делать так:

```
namespace bSpace;
class B{
    public function b(){
        $a = new aSpace\A();
    }
}
```

Либо так:

```
namespace bSpace;
use aSpace\A;
class B{
    public function b(){
        $a = new A();
    }
}
```

2. Класс импортируется/подгружается при выполнении инструкций include, include_once, require и require_once. Обычно подгрузку автоматизируют с помощью функции [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php), но при этом внутри нее все равно те-же самые includ'ы и requir'ы